# How to add binary data in microsoft graph api for uploading file using upload session

Tags: flutter, microsoft-graph-api, binary-data

For my Flutter project, to upload attachment in draft email, I have created upload session and through that I have tried to upload attachment. To do so, from the [Microsoft graph official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http) for large file attachment, need to pass like this:

```
PUT https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('a8e8e219-4931-95c1-b73d-62626fd79c32@72aa88bf-76f0-494f-91ab-2d7cd730db47')/Messages('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=')/AttachmentSessions('AAMkADI5MAAIT3k0tAAA=')?authtoken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IktmYUNIUlN6bllHMmNI
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 2097152
Content-Range: bytes 0-2097151/3483322

{
  <bytes 0-2097151 of the file to be attached, in binary format>
}
```

Can anyone please help to share how we can pass binary data into request?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
$contentBytes = file_get_contents('image/image.jpg');
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'PUT',
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Length:{$chunkSize}\r\nContent-Range: bytes {$startRange}- {$endRange}/{$fileSize}",
            'content' => $contentBytes,
        )
    );
```